# I need to give a similarity score to the elements in my dataset

Tags: r, similarity

I have a dataset in R similar to a dummy as shown :

```
Apple-3
Apple-California-4
Apple-China-3
Samsung-2
Samsung-India-2
Sony-AG-1
Sony-4
Sony-USA-4
```

I need to combine them based on a similarity score as

```
Apple-10
Samsung-4
Sony-9
```

e.g.: `Apple, Apple-China, Apple-California` get combined into `Apple` and their values get summed up.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you know how to identify a common sub-key in your strings (as in your example Apple, Samsung are simply the first tokens of your strings) or you need something that automatically identify those sub-keys or even some kind of clustering of them ?

Answer (score 1):

This should really be a string manipulation exercise but I thought this could be a FUN challenge without using string functions.

So I saved your sample as a CSV file.  Then used the dashes (-) as a separator for a data frame.

```
df <- read.csv('Manufacturers.csv', header = F, sep = '-')
```

This creates a data frame with 3 columns

```
       V1         V2 V3
1   Apple          3 NA
2   Apple California  4
3   Apple      China  3
4 Samsung          2 NA
5 Samsung      India  2
6    Sony         AG  1
7    Sony          4 NA
8    Sony        USA  4
```

Since V2 is a factor, convert it to numbers.

```
df$V2 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$V2))
```

At this point, V2 and V3 are a bunch of numbers with NAs.  Let's convert those NAs to zeros.

```
df$V2[is.na(df$V2)] <- 0
df$V3[is.na(df$V3)] <- 0
```

Add V2 and V3 together to a new column.  I called mine Quantity.

```
df$Quantity <-df$V2 + df$V3
```

Then sum the Quantity column.

```
aggregate(df$Quantity, by=list(Category=df$V1), FUN=sum)
```

And this is what I got:

```
  Category  x
1    Apple 10
2  Samsung  4
3     Sony  9
```

Happy coding!

-bg

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it by `gsub` and `aggregate`. Note that I converted it from `factor` to `character` beforehand.

```
d$names <- gsub("-.*", "", d$V1)
d$values <- as.numeric(gsub("[^\\d]", "", d$V1, perl = TRUE))
aggregate(values ~ names, d, sum)
#    names values
#1   Apple     10
#2 Samsung      4
#3    Sony      9
```

**DATA**

```
dput(d)
structure(list(V1 = c("Apple-3", "Apple-California-4", "Apple-China-3", 
"Samsung-2", "Samsung-India-2", "Sony-AG-1", "Sony-4", "Sony-USA-4"
), names = c("Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Samsung", "Samsung", 
"Sony", "Sony", "Sony"), values = c(3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4)), .Names = c("V1", 
"names", "values"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the character bit from the score first:

```
# 2 rows one with ID and one with score
company <- as.matrix(c("Apple", "Apple-California", "Apple-China", "Samsung" ))
score   <- as.matrix(c(3, 4,3, 2))

# bind columns create a frame
data <- cbind(company, score)

# this will return which rows contain the word "Apple"

n <- grep("Apple", data[,1])
```

Also useful to know is how to subset a character vector in order to get rid of the extra bits

look at `strsplit(),` `paste()` and `paste0()` functions.

the first will help you decompose the text into individual characters. The later will help you paste things back together:

another easy one to use is `substr("HEllo", 1,4)` which will output characters 1 to 4 ->  `"Hell"`